# Automatically select a feature from another layer based on shared attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, select

I have two shapefiles, A (polygons) and B (points), and I need to select all features from shapefile B that have the same attribute (for example, "Name") as shapefile A, and I need to do this iteratively for a large number of features.

Normally I would browse the table of shapefile A using the Go2NextFeature plugin, select a record, copy its name and make a "select by attribute" selection on layer B.

It would be best if whenever I select a new feature in shapefile A, all features of shapefile B with the same name would automatically be selected.